# Listar e Contar Rows de uma tabela no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

Estou tentando fazer uma listagem dos usuários que logaram e ao mesmo tempo uma contagem de quantas vezes cada usuário logou, a partir de registros de logins em uma tabela, não sei explicar muito bem, então vai um exemplo:

Tabela do MySQL (logs de logins):

```
Nome | Hora_de_Login
----------------------
Joao | 1519935575
Joao | 1519935475
Joao | 1519935275
Pedro| 1519935775
Pedro| 1519932575
```

E gostaria que o PHP imprimisse assim:

```
Nome | Numero_de_Logins
----------------------
Joao | logou 3 vezes
Pedro| logou 2 vezes
```

Comment: Dá um `count` com `group by` na sua consulta acredito que resolva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT Nome, count(Nome) 
FROM A sua tabela
GROUP by Nome
```

Em PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT Nome, count(Nome) FROM AsuaTabela GROUP BY Nome";
$result = $asuaVariavelDeConexão->query($sql);
while($usuarios = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $usuarios['Nome'] .'logou'. $usuarios['count(Nome)'] .'vezes';
}
```

Existem várias maneiras de fazer o pretendido, esta é apenas uma delas.

Comment: [**Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/).

Comment: corrigido, nao reparei